# Expo Audio - How to stop audio when i change the screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

I am using Expo Audio to reproduce a track in a component, but when i close/change the screen the audio is still playing: How can I solve this problem?

Here is my Core component where I use the CardAudio component.

```
const ObjectDetails = ({ route, navigation }) => {

  return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, width, height, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
                          .
                          .
                          .
                  <CardAudio audioPath={oggetto.audioPath} />
                 
      </View >
  )
}


export default ObjectDetails;
```

Here is my component CardAudio where i reproduce the track.

```
const CardAudio = (props) => {
    const audioPath = props.audioPath;

    const [sound, setSound] = useState(new Audio.Sound());
    const [audioStatus, setAudioStatus] = useState(false);
    const [flagAudio, setFlagAudio] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            console.log('status', audioStatus)
            if (audioStatus) {
                await sound.loadAsync({ uri: `url to get the audio file`/${audioPath} })
                try {
                    await sound.playAsync();
                    setFlagAudio(false)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            } else if (audioStatus == false && flagAudio == false) {
                await sound.stopAsync()
                await sound.unloadAsync()
                setFlagAudio(true)
            }
        })()
    }, [audioStatus])

    return <View style={styles.cardStats}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text style={styles.titolo}>Descrizione Audio</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                setAudioStatus(!audioStatus)
                Haptics.impactAsync(Haptics.ImpactFeedbackStyle.Light)
            }}>
                {
                    audioStatus == true
                        ? <AntDesign name="pausecircleo" size={SIZE / 2} color={'black'} />
                        : <AntDesign name="sound" size={SIZE / 2} color={'black'} />
                }
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </View>
}
```

In addition to the ObjectDetails screen i have another screen called Home. When the user come back to the Home screen without pressing the button to stop the audio, this last should stop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clean up the code inside useEfect(). Since this is how you structured your code, just add clean up code inside useEffect `return` statement.

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            console.log('status', audioStatus)
            if (audioStatus) {
                await sound.loadAsync({ uri: `url to get the audio file`/${audioPath} })
                try {
                    await sound.playAsync();
                    setFlagAudio(false)
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e)
                }
            } else if (audioStatus == false && flagAudio == false) {
                await sound.stopAsync()
                await sound.unloadAsync()
                setFlagAudio(true)
            }
        })()

      // this function will be fired when you leave the page
      return ()=>{
            sound && sound.unloadAsync()
   
         }
      
    }, [audioStatus])
```